# usage of "confused"

Tags: word-usage

**Note:** This post is about the usage of "confused" as an adjective rather than being a verb.

---

[From Wikipedia: Performing arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performing_arts)

> Not to be confused with Performance art.

[image]

I understand it means that

> Don't confuse Performing arts with Performance art.

How do I make the quotation with the adjective "confused" complete? Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> **Don't be confused** Performing arts with Performance art.

I looked it up on [OD](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/confused), [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confused) and [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/confused) but didn't get an example using it that way.  Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little passive-like construction.  We could say, for example

> Performing arts are confused with performance art, by many people.

As an active sentence that would be:

> Many people confuse performing arts with performance art.

So, your imperative sentence is active, you should say

> Don't confuse performing arts with performance art.

Confuse is a verb here, not an adjective.